# Which STL container can be used for quickly finding and erasing elements in it

Tags: c++, stl

I have a collection of unique ints which is always unsorted, something like

```
[1, 56, 78, 89, 887, 98, 100, 0, 23, 114, 900]
```

I would like to quickly remove an element from the container, say 887 and the result should be

```
[1, 56, 78, 89, 98, 100, 0, 23, 114, 900]
```

I am currently using a vector and using this code to erase the element.

```
container.erase(std::remove(container.begin(), container.end(), elem), container.end());
```

where elem holds the value to be removed. This works but I have do this operation a million times or more and hence I would like to see if I can use any other algorithm or container to remove elements faster.

Comment: [`std::unordered_set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set) may be what you need.

Comment: Agree with @ネロク but note that this container enforces all elements are unique (i.e. no duplicates). You didn't mention anything about that in your question, so not sure if that's a requirement.

Comment: Yes! The elements will be unique.

Comment: @ネロク Good chances are OP wants his *specific* unsorted order to be preserved by the container.

Comment: `std::vector`. It's always `std::vector`.

Comment: *but I have do this operation a million times* -- You didn't mention the size of the data set you're dealing with.  If the number of items is small, then stay with `std::vector`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie can be between 100 to 100000 elements. I will be doing this on different sized vectors

Comment: @Morpheus Then I think the question is getting close to an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).  What is the high-level issue that you're trying to solve?  Maybe using a `std::vector` to do whatever you're trying to do is not the best way, and knowing what you're trying to achieve would yield better responses.

Comment: I second PaulMcKenzie, and think the question would be more clear if you better explain your use case (maybe even turns out to be not a duplicate). You are not erasing a million times elements from a vector that contains 10 elements :P

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I have a vector of vectors. There could be a million vectors, each of size anywhere from 10 elements to 10,000 elements in each vector. So I remove elements from these vectors one by one.

Comment: @Morpheus We know all this information already.  What is being asked is what is the real high level problem you're trying to solve?